# WinJS enterPage animation not working as expected

Tags: javascript, animation, typescript, winjs

I wanted to add animations to my app on page enter, and hooked with the default `WinJS.UI.Animation.enterPage(element)`, and that worked fine sliding in the element from right to left.
I need to slide it from bottom (100px) to top. Once I overrode the default values with `WinJS.UI.Animation.enterPage(element, { top: "100px", left: "0px" })` I saw no animation at all on my screen which is weird.
However when coupled with `WinJS.UI.Animation.exitPage(oldElement)`, the animation seemed to work but I wanted to further tweak the timing.

following as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Dn127042(v=win.10).aspx#creating_custom_animations, didn't help. After using the example from "Combining custom animations and transitions" in the link, I could see only the opacity changing and the element fading in, however no translation at all. I tried the same pairing with `WinJS.UI.Animation.exitPage()`, and adding my own customExitPage - basically using from WinJS, and with just opacity... and nothing just works.
I was referring to some of the animation implementations from here as well -
https://github.com/winjs/winjs/blob/ad8691b3d5227ff1576a5d2a90a42f022498d2a9/src/js/WinJS/Animations.js, to get control over the timing.

Anyone else having this issue? or am I doing something wrong... or is it WinJS behaving bad?

EDIT: 
weirdly enough the "to top" animation with `enterPage(element, {top: "100px", left: "0px"})` started working. However the custom animation still remains elusive.

Comment: well, I was able to finally figure out the "weird behavior". The keyframes should have been set in CSS, and I was trying a few other things and apparently that's the reason that it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

well, I was able to finally figure out the "weird behavior". The @keyframes should have been set in CSS, and I was trying a few other things and apparently that's the reason that it didn't work.

However, I would probably say the explanation could have been a little more clearer in the site as well.

when we are already providing the from - to values in the javascript, I would otherwise about providing the same again as part of CSS too which is still weird.

Like mentioned in the site,
add this to css: `@keyframes custom-translate-in    { from { transform: translateY(50px); } to { transform: none; } }`

and have this in js:

`function runCustomShowStoryboard() {
    return WinJS.UI.executeAnimation(
        target,
        {
            keyframe: "custom-translate-in",
            property: "transform",
            delay: 0,
            duration: 367,
            timing: "cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.9, 0.2, 1)",
            from: "translate(50px)", 
            to: "none"
        });
}`

Never was able to figure out why and how the "bottom to top" animation started working (probably restarting visual studio helped)